# Circular dependency issue - Python

Tags: macos, pandas, circular-dependency, gdal, geopandas

I am a newbie to Python, and I have an issue that I believe is due to circular dependencies, but I have been unable to resolve it.

How can I figure out where the circular dependency is occurring, and what can I do to resolve this error (please find the terminal output below): (I use OsX Yosemite, if that helps)

```
python l3_l0.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "l3_l0.py", line 18, in <module>
import geopandas as gpd
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/geopandas/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/geopandas/geoseries.py", line 12, in <module>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall conflicting dependencies in the order of installation, and reinstall them in the correct order. This seems to the simplest solution, and it worked for m!